# after git rebase master, try to rebase from master again show the merge conflicts again

Tags: git

I have two branches: `master`, `br2`

I had few commits and pushes to `origin/br2`

Now I want to rebase `master` into `br2`

and then merge it to `master` and commit all my new changes as one big commit.

Here is what I did:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout br2 
git rebase origin/master
git rebase --continue until I resolved all conflicts

-checked everything is working

git checkout master
git merge br2 

git commit review (my alias...can ignore)

git checkout br2 

git rebase master (should have done nothing, no?)
```

**q:** I had to pull first and fix all conflicts again.  Why did this has happen?

**q:** How should i have squashed all the commits into one commit before `git commit review` ?

I saw this:

```
git rebase -i master
That command will show a list of each commit, as such:


pick fb554f5 This is commit 1
pick 2bd1903 This is commit 2
pick d987ebf This is commit 3


# Rebase 9cbc329..d987ebf onto 9cbc329
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
Edit the summary shown to you by the rebase command, leaving the commit you want to be the main commit as "pick" and changing all subsequent "pick" commands as "squash":


pick fb554f5 This is commit 1
squash 2bd1903 This is commit 2
squash d987ebf This is commit 3
```

but I wasn't sure as I have checked out master already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

q1) If you've already pushed some changes to `b2`, you would need to use force push.  `git push origin/b2 --force`.  This will replace the remote origin/b2 with the rebased local version of b2.

q2) That should work for squashing the commits.

Comment: 1) why does it have to be force? 2) when should i do this interactive rebase? after `master>> git merge br2` ? it will `rebase mater into master`?

Comment: It has to be a force push because it cannot fast forward the changes made to br2 because it's been rebased. If you have commits m1, m2 on master, then you make commits b1, b2 and push, then origin b2 has commits in this order.  m1, m2, b1, b2.  Then if there is another commit on master m3 that you rebase your local copy on top of, you locally would have m1, m2, m3, b1, b2.  This would then not allow you to do a normal push because you can only add commits that can be added to the end.  Using force push allows you to insert m3 into the commit history.

Comment: As for the squash, sorry I misinterpreted the question.  You would want to do the interactive rebase when rebasing on top of master.  You can also squash commits after the fact using: git rebase -i HEAD~3.  You can view this page on more information for interactive rebase and squashing previous commits  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: thanks for the `m1, m2, b1, b2. explanation`, but there was no problem pushing `br2 to origin/br2`. the problem started only after I did `git checkout br2; git rebase master ` does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding git rebase.

What it is basically doing is rewriting all commits from current branch onto base branch. This means that your local branch is different from remote branch (though the commits should be almost the same - except for conflicts). 
You have force your local branch onto remote by forcing your push by `git push -f origin`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but there was no problem pushing `br2 to origin/br2`. the problem started only after I did `git checkout br2;  git rebase master` does this make sense?

Comment: No, at least it shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Theoretically, it should be something like this: `git checkout br2` (should work just fine, unless someone else has made changes in parallel); `git rebase master` (solving possible conflicts using `git rebase --continue`); `git push -f origin/br2`; and than merge master with br2.